# Restrictions on laws

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation, indeterminate-forms

I'm wondering about the restrictions, my doubt is for example at $\log_a(b)=c\implies a^c=b$, how would anyone add the restrictions for this? I know the argument and the base of a log have to be >0 excluding 1, hence $a,b\in (0,+\infty)\setminus \{1\}$  but wouldn't that mean that $1^1=b$ is not valid? while it is obviously valid for b=1? I don't know i'm just confused, hopefully someone shines a light on everything, and if it's not much to ask, please tell me how to express restrictions on such complex situations? Another example would be $x^y=0$ the restrictions in my head would be $x,y>0$ because we want to avoid cases like $0^0$ or $0^{-2}$ BUT, according to what i wrote x can't be 0, but for example when x=0, $0^y=0$ is true for y>0, but WE SAID that x couldn't be 0! So i'm just in general confused by all this, hopefully the 2 examples i gave, helps to visualise the confusion i'm having better.

Comment: In $\log_ab$, $a$ must be $>0$ and $\ne1$, but $b$ only needs to be $>0$.

Comment: no? that's not true? the domain of $\log_a(10)$ for example, is $(0,\infty)\setminus\{1\}$. Oh okay that edit

Comment: This assertion of yours (except the part where you claim that mine is false) is consistent with mine.

Comment: I don't understand your second law. Are you sure you meant to put $x^y=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "conditions" on a law are simply properties which, if they are true, imply the truth of the law. Sometimes, we can prove that the conditions **must** be true in order for the law to hold, in other words that if the conditions fail, then the conclusion (the law) also fails. But that is not always true.

Let's take your law about logarithms, for example:

$$\log_{a}(b)=c \implies a^c=b.$$

The base of a logarithm can never be zero, but if $a>0$, $b>0$ and $a \ne 1$, then the rule holds. In other words, *if* $a,b,c$ are numbers which satisfy the left hand side, then they also satisfy the right hand side.

Well what if $a = 1$? Well, in that case, the rule does not apply. According to the law, if you find numbers $b,c$ such that $\log_1(b) = c$, then maybe $1^b = c$, and maybe it doesn't. The law doesn't say one way or the other. In this case we can say something even stronger: *You will never find numbers $b,c$ such that $\log_1(b) =c$, because there is no such thing as $\log_1$*. So the rule would not be helpful in that case anyway.

But, you point out, clearly if $a=c=1$, then the right hand side is satisfied if $b=1$. This is true. But it is not true *as a consequence of the law*. It's just true. You didn't use the law to work it out, you just worked it out anyway.

Comment: Thank you Anon! Yours was one of most helpful! Will look at my thing with your answer logic, now i think i got this. If not however, i will reach out to you. The purpose of all this, is because i'm making a list of laws, that include log laws, exp laws and radical laws. I was having trouble making the restrictions, may i post the code text with all the laws if yall want? And maybe get some help fro the restrictions?

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help you understand. While I don't mind giving you my perspective on that, it might clutter up the comments to fill them with laws and restrictions. If you just want to check a single case, I will gladly answer it here. If you want to check several, I recommend opening a new question.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I will definitely add a new one. Love yall

Answer (score 2):

The function $\log_a$ is defined when (and only when) $a\in(0,\infty)\setminus\{1\}$; its domain is $(0,\infty)$. So, asserting that$$\log_ab=c\implies a^c=b$$only makes sense if $a,b\in(0,\infty)$ and $a\ne1$, sense the LHS only makes sense in that case. But, yes, the RHS makes sense in other situations, and there is nothing wrong with that. In particular, the RHS makes sense in the case in which $a=c=1$, yes.

On the other hand, if we want to work with $x^y$ where both $x$ and $y$ can be real numbers, its natural definition is $\exp(y\log x)$, which makes sense only if $x>0$ (but there is no restriction on $y$). But, yes, this definition will not let us work with $0^y$. However, if we define, when $x\geqslant0$, $m,n\in\Bbb N$, $x^{m/n}$ as $\sqrt[n]{x^m}$, then this definition makes sense. And with it we always have $0^q=0$, when $q\in\Bbb Q_+$. It turns out that, with these definition, we still have $x^y=\exp(y\log x)$ when $x>0$. So, these two definitions agree when they can be applied to the same numbers. And it makes natural to assert that $0^y=0$ when $y>0$.

So, take into account exactly which definitions you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The logarithmic function and the exponential function are inverse functions between each other.

If a function is  bijective it has an inverse.

So definition of exponential function must have some restriction to make this function bijective.

$y=a^x$, $x$ a real number(domain), ($a>0$ but $a\not=1$) $y=a^x>0$(range) is a bijection

And its inverse $x=log_ay$   so $y>0$(domain), $x$ is a real number (range) and (($a>0$ but $a\not=1$)) same as exponential function